# Laravel Stripejs payment - showing method not allowed error

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe payment in my laravel app,

The stripe payment form i used is from,
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-stripe-payment-form

the html code,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-4'></div>
        <div class='col-md-4'>
            <script src='https://js.stripe.com/v2/' type='text/javascript'></script>
            <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" class="require-validation"
                data-cc-on-file="false" data-stripe-publishable-key="my_key"
                id="payment-form" method="post">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline">
                    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓" /><input name="_method"
                        type="hidden" value="PUT" /><input name="authenticity_token"
                        type="hidden"
                        value="qLZ9cScer7ZxqulsUWazw4x3cSEzv899SP/7ThPCOV8=" />
                </div>
                <div class='form-row'>
                    <div class='col-xs-12 form-group required'>
                        <label class='control-label'>Name on Card</label> <input
                            class='form-control' size='4' type='text'>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-row'>
                    <div class='col-xs-12 form-group card required'>
                        <label class='control-label'>Card Number</label> <input
                            autocomplete='off' class='form-control card-number' size='20'
                            type='text'>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-row'>
                    <div class='col-xs-4 form-group cvc required'>
                        <label class='control-label'>CVC</label> <input
                            autocomplete='off' class='form-control card-cvc'
                            placeholder='ex. 311' size='4' type='text'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-xs-4 form-group expiration required'>
                        <label class='control-label'>Expiration</label> <input
                            class='form-control card-expiry-month' placeholder='MM' size='2'
                            type='text'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-xs-4 form-group expiration required'>
                        <label class='control-label'> </label> <input
                            class='form-control card-expiry-year' placeholder='YYYY'
                            size='4' type='text'>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-row'>
                    <div class='col-md-12'>
                        <div class='form-control total btn btn-info'>
                            Total: <span class='amount'>$300</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-row'>
                    <div class='col-md-12 form-group'>
                        <button class='form-control btn btn-primary submit-button'
                            type='submit' style="margin-top: 10px;">Pay »</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-row'>
                    <div class='col-md-12 error form-group hide'>
                        <div class='alert-danger alert'>Please correct the errors and try
                            again.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-4'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js code,

```
<script>
    $(function() {
          $('form.require-validation').bind('submit', function(e) {
            var $form         = $(e.target).closest('form'),
                inputSelector = ['input[type=email]', 'input[type=password]',
                                 'input[type=text]', 'input[type=file]',
                                 'textarea'].join(', '),
                $inputs       = $form.find('.required').find(inputSelector),
                $errorMessage = $form.find('div.error'),
                valid         = true;

            $errorMessage.addClass('hide');
            $('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');
            $inputs.each(function(i, el) {
              var $input = $(el);
              if ($input.val() === '') {
                $input.parent().addClass('has-error');
                $errorMessage.removeClass('hide');
                e.preventDefault(); // cancel on first error
              }
            });
          });
        });

        $(function() {
          var $form = $("#payment-form");

          $form.on('submit', function(e) {
            if (!$form.data('cc-on-file')) {
              e.preventDefault();
              Stripe.setPublishableKey($form.data('stripe-publishable-key'));
              Stripe.createToken({
                number: $('.card-number').val(),
                cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
                exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
                exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
              }, stripeResponseHandler);
            }
          });

          function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
            if (response.error) {
              $('.error')
                .removeClass('hide')
                .find('.alert')
                .text(response.error.message);
            } else {
              // token contains id, last4, and card type
              var token = response['id'];
              // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
              $form.find('input[type=text]').empty();
              $form.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "'/>");
              $form.get(0).submit();
            }
          }
        })
    </script>
```

and the php code,

```
Route::post ( '/', function (Request $request) {
    // dd ( $request->all () );
    Stripe::setApiKey ( 'my_key' );
    try {
        \Stripe\Charge::create ( array (
                "amount" => 2000,
                "currency" => "usd",
                "source" => $request->input ( 'stripeToken' ), // obtained with Stripe.js
                "description" => "Test payment." 
        ) );
    } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
        return $e;
    }
} );
```

i used method = post in form and set a post route in routes, even it shows, method not allowed, couldn't find whats going wrong.

Additional info :
 the first 3 lines which are thrown in the error page,

```
in RouteCollection.php line 218
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
```

php artisan route:list:

```
 +--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
 | Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware   |
 +--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
 |        | POST     | /        |      | Closure | web          |
 |        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web          |
 |        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api,auth:api |
 +--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: i can't find csrf token, have you disabled it?

Comment: Have you set the routes, just in case :) Do show us your `routes.php` or `web.php` file.

Comment: @LionelChan i wrote the php logic in web.php itself, see the 3rd snippet i've posted

Comment: i 've also added {{ csrf_field() }} after form tag, still same error @ALOK

Comment: use should recheck route with this artisan command "php artisan route:list"

Comment: are you sure you need a post request on the root of  your app?

Comment: yea, no problem there is also a get function for it.

Get function loads the form, post function for handling it. @madalinivascu

Comment: have done it already, check my updated question at the end. @ALOK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is with the following input field,

```
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓" /><input name="_method"
                    type="hidden" value="PUT" /><input name="authenticity_token"
                    type="hidden"
                    value="qLZ9cScer7ZxqulsUWazw4x3cSEzv899SP/7ThPCOV8=" />
```

which has PUT https verb, when i removed this and added `{{ csrf_field() }}`. Everythng worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing form action like this:-

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="{{ url('/') }}" class="require-validation"
                data-cc-on-file="false" data-stripe-publishable-key="my_key"
                id="payment-form" method="post">
```